# Detecting Mountain Lion from within the iOS Simulator

Tags: objective-c, macos, ios-simulator, osx-mountain-lion, detection

Is there an Objective-C mechanism to detect that you are running on Mountain Lion from within the iOS simulator?  While in the iOS simulator I need to have a different code path execute on Mountain Lion that on earlier versions of Mac OS.  The optimum solution would be to detect this at runtime but I think it would be an acceptable solution to detect at compile time as well and ifdef the two code paths.  So... please post either if you have them.  Thanks!

Comment: Combining the code from the duplicate question with the result from `utsname()` and testing the kernel version should give you what you want.  (Mountatin Lion is XNU version 12.2).

Comment: I already know how to detect if I am running on a device.  This is not the same problem.

Comment: utsname() on the simulator looks promising.  I will try that.  Thanks